# Prove that $a_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We know a sequence is convergent if and only if given $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$(which depends on $\epsilon>0$) such that $\forall n\ge n_0, \lvert a_n - L\rvert \lt \epsilon$.

I already know $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$

Then, using the definition we want to find that $\epsilon>0$  such that: $$\left\lvert  \frac{n}{n+1}-1\right\rvert\lt \epsilon$$
We can rewrite this as : $$\left\lvert  \frac{-1}{n+1}\right\rvert\lt \epsilon$$

The problem comes here , where I do not really know how to proceed and how to get rid of the absolute value, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Archimedean property ensures the reult

Comment: $n$ is a positive integer.  The absolute value is just $1/(n+1)$

Comment: $n \in \mathbb N$, so $n+1> 0$, so $\frac{-1}{n + 1} < 0$. Then you can get rid of the absolute sign.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is more one of manipulating absolute values. The absolute value of a product (quotient) is the product (quotient) of the absolute values, so 
$$
\left|\frac{-1}{n+1} \right|=\frac{|-1|}{|n+1|}=\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
since the absolute value of a negative number is its negative, and the absolute value of a positive number, which $n+1$ is, is itself.

Comment: Thank you! that was really useful, now i know how to proceed.

Comment: @TheNicouU not a problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then you have to find $n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{-1}{n+1}\right|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $n\ge n_0$. Just choose $n_0=\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
a_n=\frac{1}{1+1/n}
$$
Then
$$
\left|a_n-1\right|=\left|\frac{1/n}{1+1/n}\right|=\left|1-\frac{1}{n}\right|
$$
And it is clear that
$$
\left|1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|\frac {-1}{n+1}|=\frac {1}{n+1}<\frac {1}{n} $$

It is sufficient to find $n_0$ such that

$$n\ge n_0\implies \frac {1}{n}<\epsilon $$
or $$n\ge n_0\implies n>\frac {1}{\epsilon} $$
One  can take $$n_0=\lfloor \frac {1}{\epsilon}\rfloor +2019$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon.$

Archimedes:

There is a $n_0 +1 > 1/\epsilon$, $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

For  $n > n_0 $:

$\dfrac{1}{n+1} \lt \dfrac{1}{n_0+1} \lt \epsilon.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is $1  - \frac n{n+1}$?

It is $1 - \frac n{n+1} = \frac {n+1}n -\frac n{n+1} = \frac 1{n+1} > 0$.

So $|1 - \frac n{n+1}| = |\frac 1{n+1}| = \frac 1{n+1}$

When can we say that $\frac 1{n+1} < \epsilon$?

...

Well, we can say that whenever $n+1 > \frac 1{\epsilon}$.

....

So, for any $\epsilon > 0$, let $n_0 \ge \frac 1{\epsilon}$.

then $n \ge n_0$ would mean $n+1 > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ and $\epsilon > \frac 1{n+1} = 1-\frac n{n+1} = |1 - \frac n{n+1}|$.

====

> "The problem comes here , where I do not really know how to proceed and how to get rid of the absolute value"

Notice that all of the following statements are true.

$n > 0$ and $n + 1 > 0$ and $-1 < 0$ and $\frac {-1}{n+1} < 0$ and $1 > 0$ and $\frac {1}{n+1} > 0$ and $n < n+1$ and $\frac n{n+1} < 1$ and $1 - \frac n{n+1} > 0$, etc. ad nauseum.

And that's that.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left \lvert \frac{-1}{n+1} \right\rvert = \frac{1}{n+1} \lt \epsilon \iff n > \frac1\epsilon - 1$$
So take $n_0 = \left \lfloor \dfrac1\epsilon \right\rfloor$ to guarantee that for all $n \ge n_0$, the above inequality holds.